# Install application from Microsoft store by powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, administrator, windows-store-app, windows-store

I want to install any application from Microsoft store just by running script.
I've been trying to find any information in the Internet but unsuccessfully.

I was wandering about possibility similar to remove default application:

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name "Microsoft.WindowsStore" -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that command can be used to remove any UWP application

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh852635(v=win.10))
it is not possible for *Windows 8, 8.1, Server 2012, Server 2012 R2*:

> You cannot sideload an app that has been downloaded from the Windows Store. To install Windows Store apps that are not part of your business line, you must use the Windows Store.

So, I might be wrong but I would assume there is no way in Win 10 either :/